# Colors of Plotlines aren't matching input

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I inputted colors for the scatterplot dots and for the plot lines of my graph, and the scatterplot color dots are working, but the lines seem to be randomly generating colors. How do I get the lines and dots to match color?

```
plt.scatter(x1,y1, color='y', marker="s", alpha=0.6, s=50, label='House A')
plt.scatter(x2,y2, color='r', alpha=0.6, s=50, label='House B')
plt.scatter(x3,y3, color='c', marker='v', alpha=0.6, s=50, label='House C')
plt.scatter(x4,y4, color='g', marker='D', alpha=0.6, s=50, label='House D')
plt.plot(x1, y1, color='y')
plt.plot(x2, y2, color='r')
plt.plot(x3, y3, color='c')
plt.plot(x4, y4, color='g')
```

Comment: Without concrete, reproducible data, it is hard to guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.